# Flask 404 error when initializing a connection with a react applicaiont

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

```
import os, re
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, json,request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import random


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./build/static')

# Point SQLAlchemy to your Heroku database
uri = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")  # or other relevant config var
if uri and uri.startswith("postgres://"):
    uri = uri.replace("postgres://", "postgresql://", 1)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = uri
# Gets rid of a warning
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


import models

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(
    app,
    cors_allowed_origins="*",
    json=json,
    manage_session=False
)
@app.route('/', defaults={"filename": "index.html"})
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def index(filename):
    return send_from_directory('./build', filename)
    



# When a client connects from this Socket connection, this function is run
@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('User connected!')

# When a client disconnects from this Socket connection, this function is run
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    print('User disconnected!')

@socketio.on('index')
def on_index():
    all_students = db.Students.query.all()
    random1 = random.randint(0,models.Students.query().count())
    random2 = random.randint(0,models.Students.query().count())
    total_table = []
    for student in all_students:
        total_table.append(student)
    firstStudent = []
    secondStudent = []
    while(random2 == random1):
        random2 = random.randint(0,models.Students.query().count())
    
    firstStudent.append(total_table[random1])
    secondStudent.append(total_table[random2])
    twoStudents = [firstStudent,secondStudent]
    socketio.emit('students', {twoStudents:twoStudents})

# Note we need to add this line so we can import app in the python shell
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Note that we don't call app.run anymore. We call socketio.run with app arg
    socketio.run(
        app,
      
    )
```

The react end of the application launches fine with no errors, and the database has no issues. I've used this skeleton for the base of a bunch of other projects and i've never had any issues. But for some reason i'm stuck at a brick wall setting this up. I know the issue is within the `@app.route('/')` part of the code. i've tried hard coding the html file into the url path, but that just causes other errors like `missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename' flask`. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I tested your configuration and it doesn't give me any errors. Nevertheless I offer you an alternative solution.
You can provide the entire react build folder as a static folder. You can then deliver the "index.html" as a single file in the root route. The prerequisite is that the prefix for the static url path is empty.

```
# ...

app = Flask(__name__,
    static_url_path='',
    static_folder='./build'
)

# ...

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

# ...
```